# XSLT Convert milliseconds to timecode

Tags: xslt

Hello and have a nice day!

There are two steps that I'm trying to figure out:

1. (But not in priority) to take integer from xml file with tag "duration" in milliseconds
2. I am trying to convert "duration" milliseconds into timecode that will looks like hh:mm:ss:ff , where h - hours, m - minutes, s - seconds and f - frames (25frames=1second).
   As I see the algorithm is:

```
z=milliseconds
h=z idiv (60*60*25)
m=(z-h*60*60*25) idiv (60*25)
s=(z-h*60*60*25-m*60*25) idiv 25
f=(z-h*60*60*25-m*60*25-s*25)
```

Have any idea how to make a calculation within XSLT properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <milliseconds>45045500</milliseconds>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <output>            
        <xsl:variable name="f" select="floor(milliseconds div 40) mod 25" />
        <xsl:variable name="s" select="floor(milliseconds div 1000) mod 60" />
        <xsl:variable name="m" select="floor(milliseconds div 60000) mod 60" />
        <xsl:variable name="h" select="floor(milliseconds div 3600000)" />
        <timecode>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h, '00')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, ':00')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($s, ':00')"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($f, ':00')"/>
        </timecode>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <timecode>12:30:45:12</timecode>
</output>
```

---

Note that this *truncates* fractional frames. If you want to *round* to the nearest frame, then change the variables to:

```
        <xsl:variable name="totalFrames" select="round(milliseconds div 40)" />
        <xsl:variable name="f" select="$totalFrames mod 25" />
        <xsl:variable name="s" select="floor($totalFrames div 25) mod 60" />
        <xsl:variable name="m" select="floor($totalFrames div 1500) mod 60" />
        <xsl:variable name="h" select="floor($totalFrames div 90000)" />
```

Here the result will be:

```
<timecode>12:30:45:13</timecode>
```

---

In XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can shorten the expression `floor($a div $b)` to `$a idiv $b`.

Comment: Dear @michael.hor257k Thank you a lot, your arithmetic approach is correct (mine is not) and to convert into seconds an then to calculate frames (integer division by 40ms, which is equals a length of 1 frame of 25fps) is much much better.

Comment: @AndrewSem Actually, I discovered a potential rounding error with fractional frames. See the edited version (or rather versions).